# Program for video-conferencing on actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp, videochat, video-conferencing

I looking for flash video chat on actionscript 3, that allow you make conference call i.e. video chat for more than two person, that communicate with rtmp server like in simple chats that use NetConnection and Netstream class objects to comunicate with rtmp server...